# UITaBControllerMaking the second tab the default tab on Launch

Tags: objective-c, ios, uitabbarcontroller

I am using Storyboard to develop a tabbed application , I have three tabs

is there a way to make the second tab the default tab to be loaded on launch instead of the first one ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {


        [self.tabBarController setSelectedIndex:1];
    }
}
```

put this in your viewdidAppear